# PyDrive - Erase contents of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, pydrive

Consider the following code that uses the [PyDrive](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/) module:

```py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'test.txt'})
file.Upload()

file.SetContentString('hello')
file.Upload()

file.SetContentString('')
file.Upload()    # This throws an exception.
```

Creating file and changing its contents works fine until I try to erase the contents by setting the content string to an empty one. Doing so throws this exception:

```
pydrive.files.ApiRequestError
<HttpError 400 when requesting
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/{LONG_ID}?alt=json&uploadType=resumable
returned "Bad Request">
```

When I look at my Drive, I see the *test.txt* file successfully created with text `hello` in it. However I expected that it would be empty.

If I change the empty string to any other text, the file is changed twice without errors. Though this doesn't clear the contents so it's not what I want.

When I looked up the error on the Internet, I found this [issue](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive/issues/175) on PyDrive github that may be related though it remains unsolved for almost a year.

If you want to reproduce the error, you have to create your own project that uses Google Drive API following this [tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html) from the PyDrive docs.

How can one erase the contents of a file through PyDrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

When `resumable=True` is used, it seems that the data of `0` byte cannot be used. So in this case, it is required to upload the empty data without using `resumable=True`. But when I saw the script of PyDrive, it seems that `resumable=True` is used as the default. [Ref](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive/blob/master/pydrive/files.py#L516) So in this case, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use the `requests` module. The access token is retrieved from `gauth` of PyDrive.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
import io
import requests
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'test.txt'})
file.Upload()

file.SetContentString('hello')
file.Upload()

# file.SetContentString()
# file.Upload()    # This throws an exception.

# I added below script.
res = requests.patch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + file['id'] + "?uploadType=multipart",
    headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.credentials.token_response['access_token']},
    files={
        'data': ('metadata', '{}', 'application/json'),
        'file': io.BytesIO()
    }
)
print(res.text)
```

#### References:

- [PyDrive](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)